# Where to set ios tab bar controller icons

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to Objective-C and iOS and am trying to set the icons in the Tab Bar Controller.  I think this is the line of code that I need, however, I don't know where to put it...

```
self.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemFavorites tag:0]
```

I tried to initialize the property with that line in the corresponding view controller but I received a warning and it didn't work...

Comment: What didn't work? What warning did you get?

Comment: Try placing it in your viewDIdLoad method

Comment: Yes, I placed it in viewDidLoad of the View Controller that is connected to one of the tabs in the Tab Bar Controller.  I received this warning: "Assigning retained object to weak property; object will be released after assignment".  But, in any case, I don't really want to assign during viewDidLoad since then it will only appear when that View Controller tab loads versus always appearing on the Tab Bar Controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using storyboards, when you create the viewController you're going to embed in the UITabBarController, you can set the icon IN the viewController. Magically, it will appear in the UITabBarController as well.

Make sure to embed the viewController in the tabBarController:

- Select the viewController in the storyboard, press Editor > Embed In > Tab Bar Controller (if your tabBarController isn't created yet).
- Or you can just connect the existing tabBarController with the viewController and select, in the popup window, "view controllers" above "Relationship Segue".

Also, you can make a quick tutorial to learn how to use UITabBarControllers. Here's one: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-quick-tip-creating-a-uitabbar-application-with-storyboards--mobile-10449

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It is clear from your tutorial how to add images through the storyboard, however, what I'm trying to do is to add an image from the library (UITabBarSystemFavorites) rather than my own image...

Comment: You can set a system image in the storyboard as well. Select the icon from the viewController you want to setup and select the fourth icon in the right panel (Attributes inspector); you'll see "System Item" in the Attributes inspector and from there you can choose "Favorites".

Comment: Ah, it's called "Identifier", but I found it.  Thanks!